# Pic CCS, How to get each number of a floating number to show in a 7 segment display

Tags: c, microcontroller, pic, microchip

I am coding over a pic16f818 microcontroller using pcw ccs and proteus.

Im getting a 16 bit adc comparation and trying to show on a 7 segment display.

After i convert this 0 - 1023 value into the magnitude im working on, in this time the volt amount from 0 to 5 , so

0 - 1023  bits
0 - 5     volts

Im getting a floating value from there, for example

12.34

so I multiply it by 100 in order to get a int32 number

1234

and then I try to get each character of this number.

But it doesnt work properly, is there any better way to do it?

Here is the conflictive function!

Thanks friends for your help, im so stuck on this.

```
void putSample0(){
 int32   a, m, mm, c, cm, d, dm, u;

a=12,34 * 100;
 a=1234;// for example

  m=a/1000;
  mm=a%1000;
  c=mm/100;
  cm=mm%100;
   d=cm/10;
   d=cm%10;
    u=dm/1;


// those should be the results
thousands=m;
hundreds=c;
tens=d;
units=u;

}
```

Comment: You have twice `d=...` while the second one should be `dm=...`. Always explain how it doesn't work, not just "doesn't work properly"

Comment: "But it doesnt work properly," is too vague.  Post what happens and post your expectations.

Comment: First, you don't need floating point math here for anything. Stick with integers. Second, I don't think your `a=12,34` above is doing what you might think it's doing.

Answer (score 0):

"But it doesnt work properly,", too vague fair enough sorry, it made the displays go crazy,

I just solved it by using another way, here is it. THANKS TO ALL!

```
   void putSample0(){

  a=2088 ;//adcbuffers[0];

   m=a/1000;
   c=(a-(m*1000))/100;
   d=(a-(m*1000)-(c*100))/10;
   u=((a-(m*1000)-(c*100)-(d*10)))/1;




 rb[0]=m;
 rb[1]=c;
 rb[2]=d;
 rb[3]=u;

}
```